# Pagerank information

Tags: search-engine, blogs, pagerank

I see people brag about or discuss their pagerank information.

How would one objectively criticize what someone says. For instance, if someone says their blog is "Pagerank 3" what exactly is that telling me

Do I have enough information to really understand the utility of that metric? such as:
1. what search engine
2. what search query would be necessary to see the blog in the search results
3. something else?

from my understanding "pagerank 3" means that the blog would be the third result in the search results for a particular query. but maybe this is a very rudimentary understanding of pagerank, like if it turned out they are tiers

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank

Comment: @LouisXIV read that, so what does "pagerank 3" really tell me, what context would that really be helpful to say

Comment: Note that PageRank is for *pages*, not for whole domains/sites. So "the blog" can't have a PageRank, but its front page, each article, the archive etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a more complete answer.

At the beginning of Google, results where ordered like that

---

#1 result : Pagerank score * relevancy score (for instance : 100)

#2 result : Pagerank score * relevancy score (for instance : 90)

#3 result : Pagerank score * relevancy score (for instance : 80)

---

To give an idea of what pagerank was for websites owner, google gave a metric where (it is an example):

---

real PageRank score > 10000 = PageRank metric (given by google) 5

real PageRank score > 1000 = PageRank metric 4

real PageRank score > 100 = PageRank metric 3

real PageRank score > 10 = PageRank metric 2

real PageRank score > 5 = PageRank metrick 1

real PageRank score > 0 = PageRank metric 0

---

But, by now, Pagerank has become just an indicator in hundreds of indicators explaining the rankings.

Comment: where would one see the pagerank of a particular website?

Comment: Download a pagerank plugin for Firefox or Chrome, I think it's the best.